# How to get the path of the res folder in android

Tags: android, ftp

In my android app I want to store an image on the server using an **FTP** connection. I have an image in the `res/drawable`* folder in my android app named apple.png. All my FTP connections work fine except the path of image in the `res/drawable` folder which sends to 
FTP. Please refer my code below.

```
Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.apple);//apple.png image    
                try{
                    SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();
                    ftp.connect("Serverip", server port, "myUserName", "myPassword");//works fine
                    ftp.bin();
                    ftp.cwd("Upload path of server");//works fine
                    ftp.stor(new File(url.toString()));//file not found exception
                    ftp.disconnect();
                }
```

In the above code the FTP connection is working fine but the image path of the `res/drawable` folder gives "No such file or Directory". So how to get path of `res/drawable` folder in the application?

Comment: Are you using SimpleFTP from jibble.org?

Comment: @ Mike: yes mike, i download jar file in that site only, did u find the error in above code??

Comment: No, just wanted to make sure we're talking about the same thing. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SimpleFTP.stor()` method has an overload that accepts a `FileInputStream` object. The `getResources().openRawResource()` method can supply you with the necessary Stream for your `apple.png` resource.

```
try
{
    SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();
    ftp.connect("Serverip", serverport, "myUserName", "myPassword");
    ftp.bin(); 
    ftp.cwd("Upload path of server");
    ftp.stor(getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.apple), "apple.png");
    ftp.disconnect(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks boss, The path that you given is perfect. but now i face this error "java.io.IOException: SimpleFTP was not allowed to send the file: 550 apple.png: Access is denied."

Comment: Oh, a 550. Are you sure you have write permission on the FTP server?

Answer (score 0):

```
please that image in asset folder and give it as

String stringPath = "android.resource://[your_package_name]/raw/sample"
```

Comment: how to give the path exactly in code. i try "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/sample/apple",""android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/apple" both not works.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't even understand what you're saying. Can you be more specific? And maybe use complete sentences?

Comment: @Flimzy : It is very difficult to understand butler english for shakespeare 's :-) :-)